# Redis throttling Laravel job "has been attempted too many times or run too long"

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, vonage

I want so send sms with nexmo using Laravel Queue with Redis but some jobs fail and I can't understand why.
In my local environment, I send 1 sms every 10s so here is the handle method of my job :

```
public function handle()
    { 
        Redis::throttle('throttle:sms')->allow(1)->every(10)->then(function(){
            Log::info($this->notifId." start : ".date('H:m:s'));
            try{
                $before = microtime(true);
                $response = Nexmo::message()->send([
                                'to'   => $this->to,
                                'from' => '16105552344',
                                'text' => $this->message
                            ]);
                $notif = NotificationHistory::find($this->notifId);
                $notif->nexmo_message_id=$response->getMessageId();
                $notif->save();

                $after = microtime(true);
                Log::info(($after-$before)." sec\n");
            }catch(Exeption $e){
                log::warning($e);
            }
        },function($error){
            Log::error($error);
            return $this->release(10);//release job in X second
        });
    }
```

But I get some `Illuminate\Contracts\Redis\LimiterTimeoutException` and finaly `MaxAttemptsExceededException` when I reach the tries limit.

I start my worker with `php artisan queue:work --queue=sms --timeout=60`
And I dispatch my job like this :

```
foreach($someEntities as $entitiy) {
            $notif = new NotificationHistory();
            $notif->notifiable()->associate($entity);
            $notif->message=$entity->message;
            $notif->status=NotificationHistory::$statusList[-1];
            $notif->save();
            dispatch(new SendSMS($entity->message."_".$notif->id,$entity->phone,$notif->id))->onConnection('redis')->onQueue('sms');
    }
```

When trying to send 8 sms, the firsts 5 or 6 works but I get an exception for the others.

**EDIT**
I get the same errors withtout nexmo :

```
public function handle()
    { 
        Redis::throttle('throttle:sms')->allow(1)->every(10)->then(function(){
            Log::info($this->notifId." startAt : ".date('H:m:s'));
        },function($error){
            Log::error($error);
            return $this->release(10);//release job in X second
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to see why the individual job itself is failing? The API does throttle at 30 calls per second (though phone carriers impose their own limits so internal throttling might occur after we accept the message). The SDK will attempt to self throttle, but generally that's only going to happen if you are doing 30+ API calls a second.

Comment: @dragonmantank For now, I redirect the requests to a fake endpoint so there is no API throttling. The individuals request fail multiple times due to a `LimiterTimeoutException`, when they fails too many times a `MaxAttemptsExceededException` is throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the "horizon" file which forced the tries to 3.

The queue worker doesn't in fact only run one time every 10s, it run continuously if there is something in the queue.
When it process a job, if it already have process a job in the last 10s it will remove it's current job from the queue and put it back in X seconds (defined in `release(x)`), generate a `LimiterTimeoutException` and increase it's tries value.
So when the worker reach 3 tries on the same job, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar problem. The reason was we were using AWS SQS console to check the status of the queue. When we were polling messages to test their content, the message is market as "Received", hence it counts as a first try and it is marked that in the metadata.
When the Laravel worker consumes the job it finds it has been already tried. If $tries variable for that job is not configured it means it will be considered a maximum of one try. Since it appears as consumed "once", Laravel interprets the job has run the maximum number of times, resulting in a "too many attempts" error.

Hence:

- When using AWS SQS console poll option messages are "consumed" and marked as that.
- We can add a $tries=3 configuration (or more) to allow messages that have been already consumed by the AWS SQS console.
- In any case, if job execution time is long and we request several poll to AWS SQS console and the same messages are received multiple times, we can reach the maximum of tries, so the problem can be reproduced anyway.

Conclusion:

- If you are using AWS SQS console do not 'poll' for messages too frequently or adjust the $tries Laravel job variable accordingly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).